# Ударения в словах

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно ставить ударения при склонении слов второго склонения в единственном и множ.числе: *коньяк, порт, поле*? С окончаниями в винительном и родительном падеже более-менее понятно, а как ставить ударение-непонятно. Где бы об этом почитать?

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке ударение подвижное. Вам нужно открыть орфоэпический словарь или словарь ударений  и внимательно рассмотреть словарную статью. Например, слово ПОРТ:

порт
порт, пОрта, о пОрте, в портУ; мн. пОрты, -Ов

**Русское словесное ударение**. — М.: ЭНАС. М.В. Зарва. 2001.(http://dic.academic.ru/contents.nsf/dic_udarenie/)

Всё ясно! Так же изучаете другие слова. Насчёт мн.ч. слова пОрты есть такая "запоминалка": ШОРТЫ - тОрты - пОрты.